# Как возвести дробное число в дробную степень? J2ME

Tags: java, математика, double, j2me

В J2ME нет такого метода, как `Math.pow(double,double)`.
Есть ли какая-нибудь любая формула, для возведения в дробную степень?
По крайней мере для MIDP-2.0.

И да, в J2ME также нет `Math.log(double)` и `Math.exp(double)`, поэтому другие вопросы и ответы, которые были заданы до меня не помогли мне...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516103/how-to-get-the-power-of-a-number-in-j2me

Comment: Быстрое возведение степень, корни для дробных разрядов показателя, обратная величина для отрицательных показателей. Можно сделать довольно точно. Какие требования к точности, диапазону и скорости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи можно использовать **приближенные** вычисления, приведенные в статье 2007 года [Optimized `pow()` approximation for Java, C / C++, and C#](https://martin.ankerl.com/2007/10/04/optimized-pow-approximation-for-java-and-c-c/):

- Первоначальный вариант

```java
public static double pow(final double a, final double b) {
    final int x = (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(a) >> 32);
    final int y = (int) (b * (x - 1072632447) + 1072632447);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(((long) y) << 32);
}
```

- Улучшенный вариант (2011 г.)

```java
public static double pow(final double a, final double b) {
    final long tmp = Double.doubleToLongBits(a);
    final long tmp2 = (long)(b * (tmp - 4606921280493453312L)) + 4606921280493453312L;
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(tmp2);
}
```

---

Другие примеры реализации вычисления функции `pow` приведены в ещё одной статье 2007 года, доступной сейчас только в "машине времени" / вебархиве: [WebArchive :: Creating a Java ME Math.pow() Method by Lawrence Fulton, Daniel Williams](https://web.archive.org/web/20071214092619/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/06/creating-java-me-math-pow-method.html).

В ней рассматриваются следующие варианты:

- простое целочисленное решение с использованием обычного цикла и умножений.
- решение, использующее алгоритм геометрического распада (geometric decay)
- решение, использующее функцию квадратного корня `Math.sqrt`
- приближенные вычисления натурального логарифма и экспоненты при помощи ряда Тейлора

Ещё один источник, статья на хабре 2021 г.: [Ускоряем `pow`](https://habr.com/ru/articles/584662/)

Comment: Имеет смысл указывать точность решения. Аппроксимации, которые я нашёл по ссылкам дают относительную погрешность в 25%. Напоминает анекдот: "Я умею печатать 1000 знаков в минуту! Покажи! Ой, такая чепуха получается!"

Answer (score 2):

*a<sup>b</sup>*. Если *b < 0*, выполним преобразование *a<sup>b</sup> = (1/a)<sup>-b</sup>*. В дальнейшем считаем что *b* положительное.

Разложим *b* в сумму степеней двоек: *b = ∑2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup>*, где *p<sub>i</sub>* - целые. Тогда *a<sup>b</sup> = a<sup>∑2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup></sup> = ∏a<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup></sup>*.

Если *p<sub>i</sub> > 0*, то *a<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup></sup> = (a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub>-1</sup></sup> = ((a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub>-2</sup></sup> = ... = ((...((a<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)...)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*. В последнем выражении возведение в квадрат повторяется *p<sub>i</sub>* раз.

Если *p<sub>i</sub> < 0*, то *a<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup></sup> = (√a)<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub>+1</sup></sup> = (√√a)<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub>+2</sup></sup> = ... = √√...√√a*. В последнем выражении корень извлекается *-p<sub>i</sub>* раз.

Если *p<sub>i</sub> = 0*, то *a<sup>2<sup>p<sub>i</sub></sup></sup> = a*.

Если разложить *b* по степеням двойки, то для вычисления *a<sup>b</sup>* нужны только умножение и извлечение корня квадратного. И то и другое есть в J2ME. Разлагать *b* по степеням не нужно, формат `double` уже хранит вещественное число в виде такого разложения, а Java предоставляет [средства для доступа к разложению](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.0/api/cldc/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)).

Этот способ довольно точный (теоретически он точный, мешают только округления при умножениях и извлечении корней), заметная относительная погрешность появляется для действительно больших степеней. Например если *|b| < 10<sup>9</sup>*, погрешность не превышает *10<sup>-9</sup>*.

```
    public static double pow(double a, double b) {
        if (b < 0) {
            return pow_impl(1 / a, -b);
        }
        if (b == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return pow_impl(a, b);
    }

    private static double pow_impl(double a, double b) {
        long bits = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(b);
        int exponent = (int)((bits & 0x7ff0000000000000L) >> 52) - 1023;
        long mantissa = bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL | 0x0010000000000000L;

        int max_j = 52;
        int min_j = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(mantissa);
        int j0 = 52 - exponent;

        double pow = 1;
        if (min_j <= j0 && j0 <= max_j) {
            if ((mantissa & (1L << j0)) != 0) {
                pow = a;
            }
        }
        {
            double f = a;
            int first_j = Math.max(j0 + 1, min_j);
            for (int j = j0 + 1; j < first_j; ++j) {
                f *= f;
            }
            for (int j = first_j; j <= max_j; ++j) {
                f *= f;
                if ((mantissa & (1L << j)) != 0) {
                    pow *= f;
                }
            }
        }

        {
            double f = a;
            int first_j = Math.min(j0 - 1, max_j);
            for (int j = j0 - 1; j > first_j; --j) {
                f = Math.sqrt(f);
            }
            for (int j = first_j; j >= min_j; --j) {
                f = Math.sqrt(f);
                if ((mantissa & (1L << j)) != 0) {
                    pow *= f;
                }
            }
        }
        return pow;
    }
```

**P.S.** Если существует такой относительно простой и точный способ вычислить степень, то почему его нет в J2ME? Потому что Java требует от [`pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) высокой точности:

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic.

Это означает что точность `pow` во всём диапазоне аргументов должна быть лишь в два раза хуже чем точность представления чисел самим форматом `double`. Если процессор не поддерживает аппаратное вычисление `pow`, то эмуляция с требуемой точностью будет очень медленной. Требование монотонности делает задачу ещё сложнее. А отступать от требований стандарта нельзя, Java должна работать везде одинаково (почти одинаково), это одна из целей создания языка. Какой же выход? Отрезать часть функций из спецификации. В итоге у нас интересная задача и головная боль для разработчиков.